# JSF loading properties file from system dynamicaly every 2 seconds

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, properties, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to use an `@ApplicationScoped` `@ManagedBean` to call and scheduled task that will load some properties into my JSF app every 2 seconds.For some reason is not working. 
See the steps I follow.

The first thing I do is I create a class that loads from the file system every 2 seconds:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProppertyReader {


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        SystemReader systemReader = new SystemReader();
        systemReader.schedule();
    }

    private class SystemReader {
        private final  ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        private  Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ProppertyReader.class.getName());

        public void schedule(){
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Properties properties = loadProperties();
                    LOGGER.info("Loaded property enabled:" + properties.getProperty("enabled"));
                }
            }, 0L, 2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        private Properties loadProperties() {
            try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("~/Desktop/propertiesRepo/example.properties"));
                return properties;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I go to another bean and I try to use the property:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SomeBean {
    //...
    private Properties properties = new Properties();
    private boolean enabled = new Boolean(properties.getProperty("enabled"));
    //...
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

When I try to use some bean using `#{someBean.enabled}` in a JSF if statement to show or hide a component depending on that value, doesnt seem to work:

```
<c:if test="#{someBean.enabled}">
          <h1>Works!</h1>                 
</c:if>
```

I don't what is wrong, any idea?

**Update:**
I see my mistake, with the Properties class. I am trying now to create those properties not being disposed so I cleaned a bit the code but I am getting a NullPointer when the app starts.

I splited the properties reader in 2 classes:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProppertyReader {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private SystemReader systemReader = new SystemReader();
    public static Properties appProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        schedule();
    }

    private void schedule(){
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                appProperties = systemReader.loadProperties();
            }
        }, 0L, 2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Here is where I do the reading from the system:

```
public class SystemReader {

        public Properties loadProperties() {
            try {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(new FileInputStream("~/Desktop/propertiesRepo/example.properties"));
                return properties;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

The way I call it now is:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SomeBean {

    private boolean enabled = new Boolean(ProppertyReader.appProperties.getProperty("enabled"));
//...
```

At the moment I am getting a NullPointer exception, I think I am getting close.

Comment: Did you really not realize that the session scoped bean isn't using the properties file from application scoped bean but instead creating a whole own and empty one on every construction?

Comment: @BalusC I am not sure I understand. Shouldn't the properties be in the path of the app allover the app regardless where they are called from?

Comment: Why exactly do you think that `new Properties()` call in the session scoped bean would magically hold the contents of the one created and loaded in the application scoped bean? This isn't how basic Java works.

Comment: @BalusC I thought that whenever you add something to properties with `load()` it becomes part of the path while the app is running. Maybe what I need is some kind of static variable declared in the `SystemReader` class that I can call from anywhere.

Comment: Do you also have a client-side function which re-check your <c:if> every 2 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how Java works.

To achieve your goal, you should hold the properties file as an instance variable of the application scoped bean and reload its contents everytime instead of recreating and trashing(!!) it everytime. You should in the session scoped bean also not create a completely independent instance of the properties class, but actually **use** of the one held in the application scoped bean.

Here's a rewrite:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class PropertiesHolder {

    private static final String PATH = "~/Desktop/propertiesRepo/example.properties";
    private Properties properties;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        properties = new Properties();
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    properties.load(new FileInputStream(PATH));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load properties", e);
                }
            }
        }, 0L, 2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

Note that I also added a `@PreDestroy` which shuts down the scheduler, otherwise you may be leaking away threads on every server restart until the Java runtime environment runs out of threads.

Here's how you should be using it in the session scoped bean in case you want to get the most recent value:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SomeBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{propertiesHolder}")
    private PropertiesHolder propertiesHolder;

    public void setPropertiesHolder(PropertiesHolder propertiesHolder) {
        this.propertiesHolder = propertiesHolder;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return new Boolean(propertiesHolder.getProperty("enabled"));
    }

}
```

Note that the property isn't obtained on bean's instantiation, otherwise you would on every getter call get only the value as it was at the moment of bean's instantiation and never get the updated value on subsequent requests in the same session.

Even more, the value is essentially request scoped and the session scope is therefore simply the wrong scope to hold the value. Make it a request scoped bean instead:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{propertiesHolder.getProperty('enabled')}")
    private boolean enabled;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

Comment: I understood. I was also going the same direction, and but I was getting a NullPointer, I think is because I need the `@ManagedProperty`

Comment: Apparently your IDE isn't that intelligent. Many IDEs fail in EL validation. Just run it anyway. Note that I assume that your environment supports EL 2.2 (part of Java EE 6). Based on your question history, I don't think that you're still at Java EE 5.

Comment: regarding to EL, I have this in may pom.xml:`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>` do you think could be the reason?

Comment: It works perfectly. Sorry for the confusion in the last couple of comments. It was just my IDE was confusing me. 
Thank you very much.